# sorting a partially sorted array with insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I hava an array with the first until the N element are sorted and N+1 until elemnt N+M unsorted (the array consist of N+M elements). what is the complexity of sorting this array using insertion sort? I think it's (N+M)^2, is it so?

Comment: You have to sort (M-N) elements. Assume that the entire array is actually sorted. How many comparisons are required to insert element N+1 into its proper place? How many comparisons are required to insert element M into its proper place?

Comment: Are the elements at the M last places (from N+1 to N+M) all greater then the first N elements? Or in other words is it guaranteed that `array[i] == sorted[i]` for each `i<=N` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use insertion sort, you will need O(M*(M+N)) operation. However, a better approach could be sorting the unsorted part in O(M*lgM) and then merge two sorted parts in O(N+M).